# Programming Server and Client Send and Receive Byte Array

Tags: java, arrays, sockets, client, datainputstream

Here are my 2 different programs that connect to each other:

1. SERVER

   ```
   package authenticateddns;

   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.net.ServerSocket;
   import java.net.Socket;
   import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
   import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;

   public class Server {
       public static final int PORT = 4444;
       int clientNumber;
       static String[][] url = new String[8][2];

       public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
           url[0][0] = "www.google.com";
           url[0][1] = "172.217.11.174";
           url[1][0] = "www.facebook.com";
           url[1][1] = "31.13.77.36";
           url[2][0] = "www.youtube.com";
           url[2][1] = "74.125.65.91";
           url[3][0] = "www.wikipedia.org";
           url[3][1] = "91.198.174.192";
           url[4][0] = "www.twitter.com";
           url[4][1] = "199.59.149.230";
           url[5][0] = "www.amazon.com";
           url[5][1] = "72.21.211.176";
           url[6][0] = "www.yahoo.com";
           url[6][1] = "98.137.149.56";
           url[7][0] = "www.abc.com";
           url[7][1] = "199.181.132.250";

           new Server().runServer();
       }

       public void runServer() throws IOException {
           ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
           System.out.println("Server up and ready for connection...");
           while (true) {
               ThreadPoolExecutor pool = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
               Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
               pool.submit(() -> new ServerThread(socket, clientNumber, url).start());
               System.out.println("New client has joined");
               clientNumber++;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. SERVERTHREAD

   ```
   package authenticateddns;

   import java.io.BufferedReader;
   import java.io.DataInputStream;
   import java.io.DataOutputStream;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.InputStreamReader;
   import java.io.PrintWriter;
   import java.net.Socket;

   public class ServerThread extends Thread {

       Socket socket;
       String clientName;
       int clientN;
       String url[][];

       byte[] message = new byte[4];

       ServerThread(Socket socket, int clientNumber, String[][] url)
       {
           this.socket = socket;
           clientN = clientNumber;
           this.url=url;
           message[0]=1;
           message[1]=2;
           message[2]=3;
           message[3]=4;
       }

       public void run()
       {
           try
           {
               String userURL;
               String ip = "";
               clientName = "Client" + clientN;

               //this is from the server
               BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

               //this is from the client
               PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

               DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
               //dout.writeInt(message.length);
               //dout.write(message);
               //this reads in from client
               while(true)
               {
                   if((userURL = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                   {
                       userURL = userURL.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");

                       for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                       {
                           if(url[i][0].equals(userURL))
                           {
                               ip = url[i][1];
                               break;
                           }
                           if(!url[i][0].equals(userURL)&&i==7)
                           {
                               ip = "IP Address not found";
                           }
                       }

                       //System.out.println(clientName);
                       System.out.println("    " + clientName + ": Desired URL: " + userURL);
                       System.out.println("    " + clientName + ": Sending IP: " + ip);
                       System.out.println("");

                       //send this to client
                       printWriter.println("Server Recieved Message");
                       printWriter.println(ip);
                       dout.write(message);
                       System.out.println("worked");
                   }

                   //socket.close();    
               }
           }catch(IOException e){
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }

   }
   ```
3. AND THEN YOU HAVE THE CLIENT PROGRAM

   ```
   package client;

   import java.io.BufferedReader;
   import java.io.DataInputStream;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.InputStreamReader;
   import java.io.PrintWriter;
   import java.net.Socket;
   import java.net.InetAddress;

   public class Client {

       public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
       {
           //InetAddress localIP;
           //localIP = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
           //Socket socket = new Socket("10.0.36.89", 4444);
           Socket socket = new Socket("10.1.43.10", 4444);
           String ip;
           String confirm;
           int length;

           // from client
           PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
           BufferedReader buffedReader = new java.io.BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

           //from server
           BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

           DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

           while(true)
           {

               //this sends input            
               System.out.print("Enter Destired URL: ");

               String readerInput = buffedReader.readLine();
               readerInput = readerInput.replace("Enter Destired URL: ", "");
               printWriter.println(readerInput);

               if((confirm = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
               {
                   System.out.println(confirm);
               }

               //this reads in from server
               if((ip = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
               {
                   System.out.println("Server returns IP Address: " + ip);
                   System.out.println("");
               }

               int j = 4;
               byte[] message = new byte[4];
               if(j>0)
               {
                   din.readFully(message, 0, 4); // read the message
                   j=j-1;
               }

               for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
               {
                   System.out.print(message[i]);
               }

           }
       }

   }
   ```

The issue is that the client is not receiving the byte array. It only works if you run the Server program in debugger and put a breakpoint on where it writes to Client.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Did you try manually flushing all streams after each print/write statement?

Comment: No I did not, how would I go about doing this ?